# Android Browser does not handle cross domain ajax request properly

Tags: browser, javascript

I wrote HTML/JS application which works offline - it's put on SD card and is run using default 4.1 Android Browser.

I'm making the Ajax request using jQuery to host in the internet. Since i'm running it from local filesystem it's obviously a cross domain request. The server has a mechanism based on header manipulation which enables such CD requests.  Piece of troubling code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    data : formData,
    cache: false,
    url: "http://someurlwhichhandlescrossdomain.com",
    success: function(data){
        alert("hurrayy!");

    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("bah :/");
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

The problem is that the error function is always executed, although data is being sent correctly and the server registered the request properly. The xhr.status is always 0, and thrownError is empty.

The same piece of code works correctly on Chrome on Desktop (alerts "hurray").

Currently i use a workaround based on `navigator.onLine`, and if the value is true i assume that data has been sent correctly to the server (as i don't need to read anything from server). However this solution is bad because if the connection is working, but the server is not, i can't handle it.

Any ideas?

Thanks, 
Karol

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

Comment: I don't see why this would be a duplicate. i'm using exactly the same method which has been mentioned in that question, but my question is stricly about android browser. The accepted answer in that question says how to do that, not why that's not working in android browser, which is what i asked about. Answer author claims only that it would not work on mobile browser, but the answer is from 2011, so i hope something changed in that matter....